# UWP UI Freeze While ScrollTo method called in Xamarin ListView

Tags: xamarin.uwp

We are developing chat application using `Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.91635)` for `UWP`. We are trying to implement very basic functionality which is scroll to bottom when user open any chat window or send/receive messages. It working fine where no scroll in chat window but when messages are more then we show vertical scroll bar in chat widow. we are using below line to goes to last item of list view :

```
lstMessages.ScrollTo(objlastmessage, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
```

We are use ObservableCollection to store message and bind it with listview.

Now problem is that when messenger app get any message from other user then system add it in observation collection and then move to last message in chat window, in between if if user typing message in Xamarin text editor then it freeze the UI until listivew update. so how to fix this issue. please some need hep.

Thanks

Comment: Please note the we are getting message in background thread so we are updating UI as below.

Comment: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                lstMessages.ScrollTo(objlastmessage, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                }
                        });

Comment: Could you try to provide a minimal reproducible sample?